# Is it possible that Fly a Boeing 777 plane on Moon?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-atmosphere

i always wondered that Is it possible that Fly a Boeing 777 Air Craft on Moon? if cannot how this moon lander's (Apollo) landing in Moon taking off from the moon?

Comment: Could you please use proper grammar like you have on other SE sites?

Comment: Questions that can be easily researched by a google search or Wikipedia are discouraged.   Also, this is closer to space-travel than astronomy, so that's 2 reasons for a close vote.    Grammar, I tend to forgive that cause I'm far from perfect in that myself, but bad grammar and calling people donkeys can earn some down-votes too.   I'm tempted to down-vote you for the donkeys comment.    On space flight on other planets, you might find this interesting:  https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/

Comment: On how the lander left the moon:  https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/ychki/how_did_the_astronauts_take_off_the_moon/

Comment: Two 100,000 foot pound engines. Max takeoff weight 775,000 lb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777 Divide the weight by 6 for lunar gravity = 129,100 pounds. So if you could figure out how to feed air to the engines, it'd likely have enough thrust to leave the lunar surface.

Comment: "This Boeing 777 can fly on the moon!"  "All by itself?"  "No,  I fling it!"  (bonus points if you know the reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The moon is an extremely hard vacuum with an [atmospheric pressure of $3\times10^{-15}\operatorname{bar}$](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/moonfact.html). The 777 has a [service ceiling of $13,100\operatorname{meters}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#Specifications) where Earth's air pressure is about $1/10^{\mathrm{th}}$ ground level, the air pressure is about $0.1 \operatorname{bar}$. So, there's no oxygen to burn in the engines to generate thrust, no atmosphere to generate lift against the wings. That's why rockets carry both fuel and oxidiser, and don't really bother with wings.